# jQuery Draggable / Droppable - Remove all dropped 'items'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to remove all dropped 'items' on a droppable div by pressing a single button?

Thanks,
LS

```
$("#wrapper").droppable({
                accept: '.shape',
                drop: function(event, ui) 
                    {
                        $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());
                        $("#wrapper .shape").addClass("item");
                        $(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable shape");
                        $(".item").draggable({
                            containment: '#wrapper'
                        });
                    }
                });

                 $("#trash").droppable({
                    accept: '.item',
                    drop: function(event, ui) 
                    {
                        $(ui.draggable).remove();
                    }
                });
```

I've created a div called trash, so when the items are dropped into this they are removed. I need similar functionality to this but when a button is pressed it removes all of the dropped shapes without having to drag them onto the trash div.

Comment: I'd say yes. You're welcome. (If you want more extensive help you should probably add some sample code and describe your scenario).

Comment: [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove all elements with an `item` class:

```
$('#someButton').click(function() {
    $("#wrapper .item").remove();
});
```

---

Sidenote:

Instead of selecting the dropped `.shape` element again with `$("#wrapper .shape")`, you could do

```
ui.helper.clone() // ui.helper is already a jQuery object
 .appendTo(this)
 .toggleClass("item ui-draggable shape"); 
 .draggable({
      containment: '#wrapper'
 })
```